# How dbml should be written when a stored procedure returns multiple result sets?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, dbml

Is there any way to also modify dbml so that the method in designer.cs stays as IMultipleResults?

I have a stored procedure that returns 2 sets of data.
When I drag & drop the procedure to dbml, xml and designer.cs generated by dbml

```
<Function Name="dbo.MultiResultsTest" Method="MultiResultsTest">
<Parameter Name="iCustomerID" Type="System.Int32" DbType="Int" />
<Parameter Name="iProductID" Type="System.Int32" DbType="Int" />
<ElementType Name="MultiResultsTestResult">
  <Column Name="CustomerID" Type="System.Int32" DbType="Int NOT NULL" CanBeNull="false" />
  <Column Name="Name" Type="System.String" DbType="VarChar(MAX)" CanBeNull="true" />
  <Column Name="Phone" Type="System.String" DbType="VarChar(14)" CanBeNull="true" />
  <Column Name="Email" Type="System.String" DbType="VarChar(MAX)" CanBeNull="true" />
  <Column Name="Address" Type="System.String" DbType="VarChar(MAX)" CanBeNull="true" />
</ElementType>
```

```
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.FunctionAttribute(Name="dbo.MultiResultsTest")]
public ISingleResult<MultiResultsTestResult> MultiResultsTest([global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ParameterAttribute(DbType="Int")] System.Nullable<int> iCustomerID, [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ParameterAttribute(DbType="Int")] System.Nullable<int> iProductID)
{
    IExecuteResult result = this.ExecuteMethodCall(this, ((MethodInfo)(MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod())), iCustomerID, iProductID);
    return ((ISingleResult<MultiResultsTestResult>)(result.ReturnValue));
}
```

And to get the multiple results I modified the designer.cs to like this:

```
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.FunctionAttribute(Name="dbo.MultiResultsTest")]
[ResultType(typeof(Customer))]
[ResultType(typeof(Product))]
public IMultipleResults MultiResultsTest([global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ParameterAttribute(DbType="Int")] System.Nullable<int> iCustomerID, [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ParameterAttribute(DbType="Int")] System.Nullable<int> iProductID)
{
    IExecuteResult result = this.ExecuteMethodCall(this, ((MethodInfo)(MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod())), iCustomerID, iProductID);
    return (IMultipleResults)(result.ReturnValue);
}
```

This works fine but because of the dbml, when I add more to it and save the method in designer.cs reverts back to the ISingleResult one.

Comment: You do not have well formed xml because the are multiple tags at the root of the xml.  You could simple add the multiple results to a XElement results = new XElement("Root", XElement.Parse(string));.

Comment: Thanks jdweng. I usually drag & drop tables or procedures from Server Explorer to dbml and this XML is auto generated, so not really familiar when it comes to manual modification. Where can I add the code? or maybe I can't if I use drag & drop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After bit of searching and trying I found this way works!

```
<Function Name="dbo.MultiResultsTest" Method="MultiResultsTest">
<Parameter Name="iCustomerID" Type="System.Int32" DbType="Int" />
<Parameter Name="iProductID" Type="System.Int32" DbType="Int" />
<ElementType Name="CustomerResult">
  <Column Name="CustomerID" Type="System.Int32" DbType="Int NOT NULL" CanBeNull="false" />
  <Column Name="Name" Type="System.String" DbType="VarChar(MAX)" CanBeNull="true" />
  <Column Name="Phone" Type="System.String" DbType="VarChar(14)" CanBeNull="true" />
  <Column Name="Email" Type="System.String" DbType="VarChar(MAX)" CanBeNull="true" />
  <Column Name="Address" Type="System.String" DbType="VarChar(MAX)" CanBeNull="true" />
</ElementType>
<ElementType Name="ProductResult">
  <Column Name="ProductID" Type="System.Int32" DbType="Int NOT NULL" CanBeNull="false" />
  <Column Name="ProductName" Type="System.String" DbType="VarChar(MAX)" CanBeNull="true" />
  <Column Name="Price" Type="System.Decimal" DbType="Decimal(18,2)" CanBeNull="true" />
  <Column Name="ModelNumber" Type="System.String" DbType="VarChar(MAX)" CanBeNull="true" />
</ElementType>
```

This generates the following method in designer.cs

```
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.FunctionAttribute(Name="dbo.MultiResultsTest")]
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ResultTypeAttribute(typeof(CustomerResult))]
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ResultTypeAttribute(typeof(ProductResult))]
public IMultipleResults MultiResultsTest([global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ParameterAttribute(DbType="Int")] System.Nullable<int> iCustomerID, [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ParameterAttribute(DbType="Int")] System.Nullable<int> iProductID)
{
    IExecuteResult result = this.ExecuteMethodCall(this, ((MethodInfo)(MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod())), iCustomerID, iProductID);
    return ((IMultipleResults)(result.ReturnValue));
}
```